# Storing user authentication object in the application state

Tags: reactjs, passport.js

I am going through this tutorial on logging in users using google,facebook and other passport providers.

After looking how the user is being logged in,i came across this line

https://github.com/funador/react-auth-client/blob/master/src/OAuth.js#L18

This is the source https://codeburst.io/react-authentication-with-twitter-google-facebook-and-github-862d59583105

Is it secure to store the passport user object in the application state?. What if someone uses redux tools or any other state detecting tools to copy the state and recreate it else where therefore fixing the session in another computer?.

Comment: What key values are includes user object at OAuth.js line 18?

Comment: here ``  user: {
    username: "ImANewUser",
    avatar: "https://robohash.org/imanewuser.png",
    bio: "A new user to the app."
  },
  token: "aaaaaaa.bbbbbbbb.ccccccc"
}``